# How to reset table row numbers after delete one row in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

here, i want to reset table row numbers after delete one row in table.

html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-center student-map-tbl">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SL.No</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Report</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td><td><input type="hidden" value="25" name="mapped_students[]">AA</td>
    <td> ----- </td>
    <td> ------ </td>
    <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="26" name="mapped_students[]">BB</td>
    <td> ----- </td>
    <td> ------ </td>
    <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="27" name="mapped_students[]">CC</td>
    <td> ----- </td>
    <td> ------ </td>
    <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="28" name="mapped_students[]">DD</td>
    <td> ----- </td>
    <td> ------ </td>
    <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

delete table row and reset row number by jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click','.student-map-tbl .delete',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 

    $('.student-map-tbl tbody tr').each(function(i){            
        $('.student-map-tbl tbody tr td:first').html(i+1);          
    }); 

    if($('.student-map-tbl tbody tr').length==0){
        $('.student-map-tbl tbody').append('<tr class="empty_result"><td colspan="5">There is no data.</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

My ouput row numbers after delete 3 row then, row numbers are reset like 3, 2, 4.

what is happening here?

Comment: Have you created a fiddler to simplify your probobly, often times helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your script

from

```
 $('.student-map-tbl tbody tr').each(function(i){            
        $('.student-map-tbl tbody tr td:first').html(i+1);          
    });
```

This is always accessing the first td of the first tr tag.

to

```
  $('.student-map-tbl tbody tr').each(function(i){            
        $($(this).find('td')[0]).html(i+1);          
    });
```

We are using $(this) to access the current tr and its first td.

```js
$(document).on('click','.student-map-tbl .delete',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 

    $('.student-map-tbl tbody tr').each(function(i){            
        $($(this).find('td')[0]).html(i+1);          
    }); 

    if($('.student-map-tbl tbody tr').length==0){
        $('.student-map-tbl tbody').append('<tr class="empty_result"><td colspan="5">There is no data.</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-center student-map-tbl">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SL.No</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Report</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td><td><input type="hidden" value="25" name="mapped_students[]">AA</td>
    <td> ----- </td>
    <td> ------ </td>
    <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash">delete</i></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="26" name="mapped_students[]">BB</td>
    <td> ----- </td>
    <td> ------ </td>
    <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>delete</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="27" name="mapped_students[]">CC</td>
    <td> ----- </td>
    <td> ------ </td>
    <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash">delete</i></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="28" name="mapped_students[]">DD</td>
    <td> ----- </td>
    <td> ------ </td>
    <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash">delete</i></span></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: it works you can explain this problem? actually  why my code creates bug?

Comment: $('.student-map-tbl tbody tr td:first').html(i+1);   and  $($(this).find('td')[0]).html(i+1);   are different?

Comment: @VIJAY check out my answer, you can find an explanation to your bug

Answer (score 1):

This line in your script

```
$('.student-map-tbl tbody tr td:first')
```

access the first `td` in the row each time, you need to access the first `td` for each row.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.student-map-tbl .delete', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();

  $('.student-map-tbl tbody tr').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find("td:first").html(i + 1);
  });

  if ($('.student-map-tbl tbody tr').length == 0) {
    $('.student-map-tbl tbody').append('<tr class="empty_result"><td colspan="5">There is no data.</td></tr>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-center student-map-tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SL.No</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Report</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="25" name="mapped_students[]">AA</td>
      <td> ----- </td>
      <td> ------ </td>
      <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash">x</i></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="26" name="mapped_students[]">BB</td>
      <td> ----- </td>
      <td> ------ </td>
      <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash">x</i></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="27" name="mapped_students[]">CC</td>
      <td> ----- </td>
      <td> ------ </td>
      <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash">x</i></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="28" name="mapped_students[]">DD</td>
      <td> ----- </td>
      <td> ------ </td>
      <td><span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash">x</i></span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```